Routing between two subnets not working as expected
the topology in question is depicted below:

These are basically two separate rings with two VLAN2 attached network subnets (for transport / routing inside of a single ring). There are other subnets in each of the rings (I omitted for the sake of simplicity), hence that transport VLAN.
There's a node switch acting as a router, having both VLAN2 in "red" transport network and VLAN22 in "blue" transport network - simply being part of both subnets, as it should be.
End hosts (red and blue PCs) are in the 10.X.170.0/24 subnets and should be able to communicate with each other. The problem is, they aren't - if the configuration is done, as depicted.
If done that way, traceroute dies exactly at the node switch (the router one). Even though the routes are properly configured.
Now the strange thing: the whole setup WILL work, but only when you introduce two additional static routes, which are:
ip route add 10.200.253.0/24 10.12.253.201 at the leftmost blue switch (the edge one, connecting to host)
ip route add 10.12.253.0/24 10.200.253.201 at the rightmost red switch
In other words, only when both edge switches know each others' transport subnets (the ones associated with their respective VLAN2s), the whole thing starts to work.
This is counterintuitive, but is there any logical explanation behind such behavior?
Switches in question belong to two manufacturers, blue ring is done using Alcatel Lucent, red one is done using Belden switches (Hirschmann brand).
Here's the config for the rightmost, red switch:
    ! VLAN :
vlan 1 1x1 stp disable flat stp disable name "VLAN 1"
vlan 2 flat stp disable name "VLAN 2"
vlan 2 port default 1/21
vlan 2 port default 1/22
vlan 170 flat stp disable name "VLAN 170"
vlan 170 port default 1/19
! IP :
ip service all
ip interface "VLAN 2" address 10.200.253.200 mask 255.255.255.0 vlan 2 ifindex 6
ip interface "VLAN 170" address 10.200.170.1 mask 255.255.255.0 vlan 170 ifindex 8
!
ip static-route 10.12.170.0/24 gateway 10.200.253.201 metric 1
!
ip wccp admin-state enable

Here's the one for the "node" switch:
! VLAN :
vlan 1 1x1 stp disable flat stp disable name "VLAN 1"
vlan 2 flat stp disable name "VLAN 2"
vlan 2 port default 1/1
vlan 2 port default 1/2
vlan 2 port default 1/48
vlan 22 1x1 stp disable flat stp disable name "VLAN 22"
vlan 22 port default 1/43
! IP :
ip service all
ip interface "VLAN 2" address 10.200.253.201 mask 255.255.255.0 vlan 2 ifindex 1
ip interface "VLAN 22" address 10.12.253.201 mask 255.255.255.0 vlan 22 ifindex 2
!
ip static-route 10.12.170.0/24 gateway 10.12.253.12 metric 11
ip static-route 10.200.170.0/24 gateway 10.200.253.200 metric 1
! Spanning tree :
bridge mode 1x1
!
ip wccp admin-state enable

And here for the leftmost, blue switch:
    enable
vlan database
vlan add 2
vlan add 170
name 2 VLAN2
name 170 VLAN170
routing add 2
routing add 170
exit
configure
ip routing
ip route add 10.200.170.0 255.255.255.0 10.12.253.201
spanning-tree mst priority 0 4096
interface 1/1
vlan participation exclude 1
vlan participation include 2
vlan pvid 2
exit
interface 1/2
vlan participation exclude 1
vlan participation include 2
vlan pvid 2
exit
interface 3/8
no spanning-tree mode
vlan participation exclude 1
vlan participation include 170
vlan pvid 170
exit
interface vlan/2
ip routing
ip address primary 10.12.253.12 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
name "VLAN2"
no security-status no-link
exit
interface vlan/170
ip routing
ip address primary 10.12.170.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
name "VLAN170"
no security-status no-link
exit
save
exit

Thanks in advance, this might be a noobish question, but honestly - it's first time I see a static routing between two adjacent subnets that actually requires putting additional two static routes just to make it work.
As @FrameHowitzer noted, there is no dynamic routing - everything is static.
EDIT: I fixed the subnet range, indeed there has been a typo - I had to sanitize the config  it and made one copy-paste too much.
All subnets have /24 mask. Yes, STP is enabled in both loops.
*The whole thing here is that .170 "red" and "blue" subnets won't "see" each other unless two additional routes are entered at the edge routers. English is not my native language so I'm not sure if I can express myself clearly -it can clearly be the case, so please forgive me:
IF we have A and B transport networks assigned to both respective rings (VLANs) AND leftmost red router X in the middle is part of both, then it is impossible for endpoint devices (PCs) to reach their respective counterparts EVEN IF their default gateways are set to edge routers (which are in turn parts of either A or B subnet) AND said edge routers already have their static routes (towards .170 subnets) set to router X.
The above setup will work only, if route toward red transport subnet (via X) appears on the leftmost blue router (edge), and conversely - if the route towards blue transport subnet appears on the red rightmost router (edge). I am puzzled, because in order for a static route between two subnets to work, all that is really required is a device that is part of both - and any edge routers that exist point to it as a gateway to the other. The setup on the picture should do precisely that and for some, unknown to me, reason it won't - unless the routes are adjusted as described above. I was thinking about STP disabling a port associated with one of the transport subnets - but I checked that and, sadly, it wasn't the case.*

Routing requires routes to be present, on all participating routers - either statically by the admin or dynamically using routing protocols like OSPF. Please edit your question and add the relevant router configurations (in text format, using the editor's {} preformat option).

You don't mention any routing protocols in use to help any of the equipment in question learn routes from each other. That means you have to add static routes everywhere (other than the 'connected' routes learned on a device when an interface is given an IP in a connected network) to make things work.

Here "leftmost, blue switch" I think you have a lack of static routes as I can see only one.
Regards,

A router needs to learn subnets in one of these three ways:

subnet is directly connected
a static route is configured by the admin
a dynamic route is learned from a routing protocol like OSPF

If there's no route to a packet's destination and no default route, the router has no other choice than drop the packet.
From your diagram, there are four subnets:

10.12.170.0/24 - blue PC and leftmost blue switch
10.12.253.0/24 - blue switches and leftmost red switch
10.200.253.0/24 - red switches
10.200.170.0/24 - red PC and rightmost red switch

A packet from the blue PC to the red PC requires a route to 10.200.170.101 on these hops:

leftmost blue switch (missing, there's only a route for 10.200.170.0/30)
leftmost red switch (seem to be OK)

The reverse direction works the same way. Step through each hop in turn to see where the packet goes. When using tracert / traceroute, a failing hop often indicates the lack of a route back to the ping source.
A side note: since you seem to configure switches in a redundant loop you need to configure a spanning tree protocol on all switches to block one of the links. We can't really see whether that configuration is complete.
